# Close an open path with an open shape in Photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, shapes, path

I created a path in CS6, which ends with horizontal lines on both sides. I want to connect them to an (open) semicircle above them, thus the path would be closed.

I created a circle (automatically on a new layer), and deleted its lower anchor point so only the upper half remained.

When I try to merge the shapes from the two layers via the layers menu, CS6 always closes the semicircle with a horizontal line before merging it, and also closes my drawn path with another horizontal line.

Is there any possibility that I could close the path via the existing open semicircle?

Comment: I'm having difficulty envisioning a "closed F" since an F has 3 open ends. I think you may need to provide some sample images to better explain. In general, you use the Pen tool to close or connect anchor points.

Comment: Oh my. That was actually a typo. No wonder you couldn't imagine that!

Comment: ...I'm a weird yet typical designer, so...: do you have a screenshot? That would help wonders with understanding. Thanks!

Comment: I just noticed one mistake I made: When I drew the "path", the pen tool was in shape mode. Here's a screenshot of the initial situation: [cs6 shape problem](http://i60.tinypic.com/287n2af.jpg)   When I would merge the two, the semicircle would "close" itself at the bottom, thus overwriting the empty space in the middle of the horizontal line.  But I just tried to reproduce it with a path, and I think it would be even harder that way to achieve what I wanted. I found the answer, i.e. the workaround, anyway (see below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple but effective workaround for this type of problem, which I only found out later and would like to share. You can create a perfect semi-circle with the pen tool, starting from one of the endpoints of the horizontal line. You only have to mark the "top" spot of the circle, which is on the line perpendiucular to the existing horizontal line and crossing its center, and in a distance which is (length of the horizontal line)/2 (= the radius of the circle). You mark that spot via two guiding lines, and activate "snap on guiding lines" and "on edges". Then you start adding spots via the pen tool: you add the top spot and curve the line by clicking and holding down the left button and simultaneously holding SHIFT; you then move on towards the other side. When you are above the other endpoint of the horizontal line, the curve helper will snap in. Next, you click on the other endpoint of the horizontal line. Your perfect semi-circle is finished, and the path is closed. If the top spot is not exactly in the center, you can still CTRL-select it and move it, it will snap in the guiding lines.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the two objects are on different layers is irrelevant. I believe the effect you're looking for will be achieved by selecting both shapes, then under Object>Pathfinder>, select Add.

Note: In order for the two paths to combine, they must overlap. If they do not overlap or if at least one anchor from each object does not share the same location, then you will only see the respective paths close.

Comment: Note this is asking for Photoshop, not Illustrator.

Comment: ah nuts. Thanks for pointing that out, Scott.